# Scalability of WCF over NetHttpBinding with WebSockets

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, websocket, scalability

I am developing an application server that requires a large amount of connected users (stateful with "duplex" functionality, hence the sessions). Traditionally I would develop this using Sockets as opposed to WCF with NetTcpBinding due to its known deficiency in scaling well under heavy loads - and by heavy loads I mean thousands of concurrent sessions and over 100+ calls per second.

However I have been reading all over the place that WebSockets over IIS 8+ can handle 10ths of thousands of simultaneous connections.

In lieu of maintainability by anyone in my team I would rather migrate to WCF if at possible. It is much simpler to develop a service application using WCF than sockets directly.

Can somebody attest such claim? That WebSockets is handling well a large number of connected users (thousands or 10ths of thousands) of simultaneous sessions?

Care to share examples?

Cheers,
Robson

Comment: "...due to its known deficiency in scaling well under heavy loads...", that is interesting. Do you have any further information supporting that statement? Thanks.